# How to remove value in lists and tuples

Tags: python-3.x

If I use product function from itertools to generate a list like below:

```
b = [i for i in product('TF', repeat = 3)]
```

> [('T', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'F'), ('T', 'F', 'T'), ('T', 'F', 'F'), ('F', 
>       'T', 'T'), ('F', 'T', 'F'), ('F', 'F', 'T'), ('F', 'F', 'F')]

if the second value in the tuple = F, pop this item from this list. how can I do this?

> [('T', 'T', 'T'), ('T', 'T', 'F'), ('F', 'T', 'T'), ('F', 'T', 'F')]

Comment: outside the yellow box is the expected output.,

Comment: Please format your code as code. Align the post with the conventions used here. Thank you! :)

Comment: `[i for i in product('TF', repeat = 3) if i[1] != 'F']`